# How to download images using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape:
https://www.jny.com/products/cuff-sleeve-v-neck-top-floral-spice-combo

I want to download high resolution product images. This is my code:

```
img= response.xpath('//div[@class="slick-track"]/li[@class = "image-track"]//img/@src').get()
print(img)
```

This is returning None. 
I have downloaded using Selenium but it is quite slower. Is there any other solution?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

Comment: It requires you to have a URL. I am unable to get that using this xpath even though it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Just try below xpath.

```
img= response.xpath('//div[@class="slick-track"]//li[@class = "image-track"]//img/@src').get()
print(img)
```

Snapshot:

[image: Chrome dev tool output]

Comment: Still gives none

Comment: If  I try above xpath in chrome dev tool.its giving me 7 records.this should work.see attached snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy provides reusable item pipelines for downloading files attached to a particular item (for example, when you scrape products and also want to download their images locally). These pipelines share a bit of functionality and structure (we refer to them as media pipelines), but typically you’ll either use the Files Pipeline or the Images Pipeline.